# Show similar questions in Android

Tags: feature-request, android-app

In the web interface, when I start writing a question I get to see similar subjects (often really totally unrelated, but that is another point :-) , but not on Android. This is useful (it would presumably have saved me from posting the same question twice, I thought the first post had failed, for one).

Comment: I miss this too - not when writing questions, but when reading them.